# Close unedited draft without asking for save or delete in ios-app

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app

If I open and close the existing draft via Cancel button (left top) without any edit attempts, app asks me:

[image: del-save]

In this case asking about save/delete draft is not needed. It's little bit annoying if I only want to inspect draft content.
My request is to remove asking in this case.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Make a new draft (if already have one, go to step 4):

   > [image: new draft]
2. Add a title:

   > [image: title]
3. Save draft via Cancel button:

   > [image: save]
4. Open existing draft for edit:

   > [image: existing draft]
5. Tap "Cancel" button (don't edit anything):

   > [image: cancel]
6. Save/Delete dialog appears (should not), same as on step 3.

---

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: This shouldn't happen.  If all the fields are empty (or unchanged for edits) it should instantly dismiss.  Are there specific posts this is happening on or is it everywhere?

Comment: @BrianNickel this one is for drafts. Create a new question via draft section, save it, then try to open and close (via cancel button).