# Canceling edit of not yet loaded post

Tags: bug, ios-app

If you open post to edit and cancel edit before post has been loaded, then "Delete/Save draft" dialog has appeared.

> [image: cancel edit]

In this case there is no need to ask because nothing edited.

To easily reproduce you could disable WiFi before pressing Edit button under the post body.

Possibly related question: [Close unedited draft without asking for save or delete in ios-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287600/339911)

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)